# i want to change the input border-bottom to blue while the input is focus or valid

Tags: html, css

the following html code is:

```css
 .inputBox input:focus ~ input,
 .inputBox input:valid ~ input{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0000cd;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputBox">
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required autofocus>
         <label class="noselect" for="name"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Name :</label>
</div>
```

the same thing worked for my label element

i want to change the input's border bottom color to blue

iam asking question for first time idk i described every thing or forgot something to explain

thank you in advance

Comment: remove ~ input, it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will show your bottom border blue

```
  .inputBox input:focus,
  .inputBox input:valid {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0000cd;
    outline: none;
  }
```

This is if you need to show only the blue border

```
  .inputBox input:focus,
  .inputBox input:valid {
      border-color: transparent;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #0000cd;
      outline: none;
  }
```

```css
.inputBox input:focus,
.inputBox input:valid {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0000cd;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="inputBox">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off" required autofocus>
  <label class="noselect" for="name"> <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Name :</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the sibling selector ("~ input"). It selects inputs that follow ".inputBox input:focus".

```
 .inputBox input:focus,
 .inputBox input:valid{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #0000cd;
 }
```